# How to get a value from inside of an element in HTML and set it as variable in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have an element.

```
<span id="coins">50</span>
```

And I want to get the 50 out of it and set it as x (something like that)

```
var x = ("#coins")
```

But I'm not sure how to do it...

Comment: var x = document.getElementById("coins").childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want `x` to end up as a number, so you could do this:

```
var x = +(document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML)
```

Which will get the innerHTML of the element, then convert it to a number using the `unary +`.

This also works:

```
var x = parseFloat((document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML));

var x = parseInt((document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML), 10);
```

There is also an `innerText`  as well as `.textContent` property, but they doesn't have as wide of support.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the element like so:

```
var spanEl = document.getElementById('coins');
var x = spanEl.innerHTML;
```

If you want to cast it to an `int` you can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var spanEl = document.getElementById('coins');
var x = parseInt(spanEl.innerHTML, 10);
```

Note that `10` is the second argument in the `parseInt` function. That indicates that you want to parse the number base 10.

Answer (score 1):

Can't properly style it in the comments, but this is what I would recommend doing:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("coins").childNodes[0].nodeValue); 

x = isNaN(x) ? 0 : x;
```